# Masking the charging voltage on 12v battery

Tags: battery-charging

I am not an electrical engineer hence the odd question.  I can wire and solder though.

I have a dynamo charging a 12v 110AHr starter battery.  The dynamo has a electronics that monitor the battery voltage when charging.  When the voltage reaches 14.5 the dynamo stops, not an efficient way to charge.

Would it be possible to 'mask' or 'pull down' the battery voltage on the live feed to make the dynamo run longer.   I know that one is thinking how will I know when the battery is charged?  That will be taken care of, I just need to mask the voltage for about 5min.

I hope this makes sense

thanks

Cliff

Comment: Draw a schematic/diagram.

Comment: How is to "make the dynamo run longer" is more efficient than stopping it? Are you trying to overcharge the battery (bad idea)?

Comment: Right.  Sorry should have given more detail at the start.I'm going to use the starter battery as a buffer for connection to a B2B charger.  The B2B needs around 3-4min to start then it will take over the charging of leisure batteries and the starter batt. via the dynamo.  The dynamo is obviously inefficient and the B2B will solve this.

Comment: A resistor voltage divider feeding the dynamo monitor point will reduce the voltage it sees... this sounds like a bad idea if it will cause the battery to over charge!

Comment: ThanksThe 'dynamo monitor point' being the live feed from the dynamo?

Comment: Question does not make any sense whatsoever. The "charge to 14.4V and then disconnect" method is the most *time* efficient method to charge a 12V lead-acid battery. The battery is full at 14.4 or 14.5 volts across its terminals.

Comment: We very much need to see some kind of wiring diagram or schematic or photograph. Also, it is not a good idea to go much over 14.4V unless the battery temperature is very cold. If the battery is warm, 14.4 might be too high.

Comment: I know it's tiresome but perhaps a little more info?

Comment: As mentioned I'm only using the starter battery as a buffer until the B2B takes over.   There is no danger of a batt being overcharged the B2B will sort that.  At the moment the dynamo is cutting out before the B2B can startup, but you are right a diagram is needed.   Will try to get one on here, bear with me.  thanks Cliff